# error TS2554: Expected 2 arguments, but got 1

Tags: angular, typescript

I upgraded my ionic app to Ionic 4 from Ionic 3 which is been giving me camera issues. This error displayed on console on **ionic serve**

> ERROR in src/app/register/register.page.ts(50,4): error TS2554:
>   Expected 2 arguments, but got 1.
>       [ng]     src/app/register/register.page.ts(53,63): error TS2749: 'Camera' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here.

Below is **register.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ScrollDetail } from '@ionic/core';
import { NavController, LoadingController, ToastController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions }  from "@angular/http";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { SignaturePad } from 'angular2-signaturepad/signature-pad';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-register',
  templateUrl: './register.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./register.page.scss'],
})
export class RegisterPage implements OnInit {

showToolbar = false;
capturedSnapURL:string;




onScroll($event: CustomEvent<ScrollDetail>) {
    if ($event && $event.detail && $event.detail.scrollTop) {
      const scrollTop = $event.detail.scrollTop;
      this.showToolbar = scrollTop >= 225;
    }
}

 signature = '';
 isDrawing = false;

  options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    cameraDirection:0
  }

  clickedImagePath:any;

  @ViewChild(SignaturePad) signaturePad: SignaturePad;


   constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private camera: Camera, private http: Http, public loading: LoadingController, public storage: Storage, public toastCtrl: ToastController) {

  }


  ngOnInit() {
  }


ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.signaturePad.clear()
    this.storage.get('savedSignature').then((data) => {
      this.signature = data;
    });
  }


  drawComplete() {
    this.isDrawing = false;
  }

  drawStart() {
    this.isDrawing = true;
  }

  savePad() {
    this.signature = this.signaturePad.toDataURL();
    this.storage.set('savedSignature', this.signature);
    this.signaturePad.clear();
   /* let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
      message: 'New Signature saved.',
      duration: 3000
    });
    toast.present();*/
  }

  clearPad() {
    this.signaturePad.clear();
  }


clickImage(){
    this.camera.getPicture(this.options).then((imageData) => {
      // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
      // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
      let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
      this.clickedImagePath = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
     }, (err) => {
      // Handle error
     });
  }



}
```

Could someone please point me to what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you imported Camera into the correct module, probably your app.module, and declared it?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to include Camera in the providers array in app.module.ts

```
import { Camera } from '@ionic-native/camera';

providers: [
   Camera 
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to import the camera plugin

```js
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
```

and in the HTML give the SignaturePad component an Id (like 'componentId') and change your view component code to below

```js
@ViewChild('componentId', { static: true } ) signaturePad: SignaturePad;
```